# Read file block by block with timer

Tags: c, cpu, delay, disk

My task is to measure latency/delay between CPU and disk. Mission is to get time which disk needs to get ready for write or read block/file.

One block on my disk NTFS has size 4096 bytes.

Scenario #1: load block by block from disk to memory, problem is every time I get 0.0 milliseconds for first read block.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

float timedifference_msec(struct timeval t0, struct timeval t1)
{
    return (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t0,t1,t2;
    float elapsed;
    size_t newLen;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        FILE *fp0=fopen("D:\\Download\\foot.txt", "ab+");
        ftruncate(fileno(fp0), 1024*1024*4);
        fclose(fp0);

        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        char *source = NULL;
        FILE *fp = fopen("D:\\Download\\foot.txt", "rb");
        if (fp != NULL) {
            /* Go to the end of the file. */
            if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
                /* Get the size of the file. */
                long bufsize = ftell(fp);
                if (bufsize == -1) { /* Error */ }

                /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
                source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));

                /* Go back to the start of the file. */
                if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { /* Handle error here */ }

                /* Read the entire file into memory. */
                gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
                while (newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), 4096, fp) > 0) {
                    gettimeofday(&t2, 0);
                    if (newLen == 0) {
                        fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
                    } else {
                        //source[newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
                        i++;
                    }
                    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
                    if (i == 0){
                        elapsed = timedifference_msec(t0, t1);
                    } else {
                        elapsed = timedifference_msec(t1, t2);
                    }


                    printf("%d Code executed in %f milliseconds.\n", i, elapsed);
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
        free(source);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Scenario #2: write block by block, same problem

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define O_DIRECT 040000
#include <malloc.h>
#include <windows.h>

float timedifference_msec(struct timeval t0, struct timeval t1)
{
    return (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t0, t1, t2, t3;
    float elapsed;
    size_t newLen;
    char c [4096];
    char *source = __mingw_aligned_malloc(4096, 4096);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int fdw = open("D:\\Download\\foot.txt", O_WRONLY |O_DIRECT, 00666);

    for(i=0; i<4096; i++){
        c[i] = 0;
    }

    memcpy(source, c, sizeof(c));
    for(j=0; j<1024; j++){
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        write(fdw, source, a);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed = timedifference_msec(t0, t1);
        printf("j = %d, time in %f milliseconds.\n", j, elapsed);
    }

    close(fdw);
    free(source);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `timedifference_msec(t0, t1);` seems to measure the time for `printf("%d ", i);
            i++;`. No reading involved here.

Comment: The [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function reads a *line* from the file, not a "block". For block-wise reading use [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) (and open the file in binary mode).

Comment: your test will test nothing but memory cache, actually, if you really want to test disks access, you need to use direct access to dist (open with O_DIRECT) to bypass the cache, or to write enough data to fulfill the cache and force the kernel to write pages on disk (and to keep the measure accurate, you need to write size at least 3 or 4 time you RAM size, which might take a very long time).

Comment: Oh and note that using the standard C file streams incur some overhead from using direct system calls to read from and write to files. Considering your mention of NTFS, I recommend you use [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) and [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) instead.

Comment: edited code section, so is it better switch to systemC to complete this task?

Comment: Note: `while (newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), 4096, fp) > 0) {` does **not** do what you intend.(in this case, it is not *yet* dangerous) BTW: `if (newLen == 0) {` is not reachable.

Comment: @wildplasser how to read file block by block then?

Comment: Either you simplify your loop, or you study operator precedence and add some parentheses. (I'd prefer the first)

Comment: if I understand it correctly, with fread() I read in first iteration 4096 bytes from file(first block of 1024 blocks), in second iteration read second block of 1024 blocks.
 `while ((newLen = fread(source, 1, 4096, fp)) > 0)` I dont want data from that block, just get time of reading block

Comment: @OznOg I tried method with O_DIRECT in scenario #2 but result is same.

Comment: I don't see where you write 30Gb and moreover you write zeros, and this is a bad idead: some filesystems are clever enough to "fake" zeros block (they just do'nt write zeros on disk), you should initialize you buffer with random data. BTW, you want to test access to disk or acess to filesystem? if you want to test the disk itself, you need to access it without filesystem